# Show that $f(z) = 5\sin(z) - \exp(z)$ has exactly one zero in a region.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f(z) = 5\sin(z) - \exp(z)$.

To show that this function has exactly one zero in the square $\bigl\{z \in \mathbb{C} : \lvert\mathcal{R}(z)\rvert < \pi/2 ,\:\lvert\mathcal{I}(z)\rvert < \pi/2 \bigr\}$, I was thinking of using Rouché's theorem. However, I can't seem to find functions with a zero in the square region that fit the theorem.
How does one approach this problem?

Comment: Maybe you could use the argument principle if you can expand $f'(z)/f(z)$.

Comment: It could be easier as $f(\pm\frac\pi2+iy)=5i\sinh(y)-\exp(\pm\frac\pi2+iy)$ and $f(x\pm i\frac\pi2)=5\sin(x)\cosh(\frac\pi2)\pm5i\cos(x)\sinh(\frac\pi2)\mp i\exp(x)$ which should allow an easy computation of when the function value is in what quadrant and thus in sum of the winding number.

Comment: I see. I am in the process of writing this out. @LutzL, wouldn't $f(± \frac{\pi}{2} + iy) = ±5 \cosh(y) - \exp(\frac{\pi}{2} + iy)$?

Comment: Yes of course. I was not thinking clearly about the roots of sine and cosine.